# SQL Server stored procedure is very fast on my local but slow on QA

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I have two identical databases (same schema and data) that I use both in my local development and for QA. There are a couple of stored procedures that run very fast on my local machine, but are slow on QA. I can't figure out why.

- QA: 10GB of ram, 64 bit, SQL Server 2012
- Local: 8GB of ram, 64 bit, SQL Server 2012.

Can anyone point me to where/how to investigate this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: The first place to look would be the execution plan and the results from the IO and TIME statistics.

Comment: what is 'local" and what is "QA" are these both machines that you own? are they running on remote servers somewhere in the cloud?

Comment: "same schema" - Does that include the indexes?

Comment: Same indexes? both with up-to-date stats?

Comment: Yes, same schema and same indexes. I run the stored procedures directly on both machines in SQL management studio.

Comment: What do you mean by slow?  Like Sean wrote, provide the execution plan and time.  Also, is the stored procedure doing any update to the DB?

Comment: No, the stored procedure only retrieves from the database, no update. Executing it on local machine takes 3 seconds vs 13 seconds on QA machine. I did look at execution plan and time but did not find anything useful. I'll take a closer look.

Comment: Maybe you should rebuild/reorganize and update statistics and see if you get a boost in speed - Your migration could have added or removed huge chunks of data.

Comment: smells like parameter sniffing (excuse the pun). try drop and recreate or recompile the SP in QA.

Comment: Check if max degree of parallelism is not 0 (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181007(v=sql.105).aspx) - if it is 0, change it

Comment: Did both suggestion made by @lrb and gotqn but got no difference. Max degree of parallelism was 0 on QA machine and 8 on my local. Change QA to 8 and got no improvement.Updating stats did not help either.

Comment: Anything (raw queries or stored procedures) run on QA is slower than on local.